# Call a function when appending an input into DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page that appends and removes inputs from DOM using jquery. Some of them share a class ("numeric"). Once each input is appended, my code should call .numeric() to every new input with "numeric" class. I defined this block at the beginning of the code,

```
$('input.numeric')
    .live('load', function() {
        $(this).numeric();
    });
```

but load seems not to be related to appended nodes after DOM is loaded. Ready event isn't working either.

How could I do that? Thanks mates

**Edit:** I managed to solve this following @BGerrissen methods in a more general way. I already defined a wrapper for appending (which I called draw), and then each time I append anything, I trigger `$(document).trigger('appended')`, so it is easy to track anywhere. Then I use

```
$(document)
     .bind('appended', function() {
        $('input.numeric').numeric();
    });
```

To do what I need. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When appending inputs, fire a custom event as well.

```
var child = $("<input class='numeric' />");
$("#parent").append(child);
child.trigger("appended");
```

Then you can hook events to it for your purpose:

```
$('input.numeric')
    .live('appended', function() { // Use .on() method from jQuery 1.7 and up
        $(this).numeric();
    });
```

**NOTE:** As of jQuery 1.7, .live() is deprecated. Use .on()

Or use a helper method for firing the event on append.

```
function appendAndFireAppendEvent( parentExpr , childExpr ){
    var child = $( childExpr );
    $( parentExpr  ).append(child);
    child.trigger("appended");
}

// usage
appendAndFireAppendEvent( "#parentElement" , "<input class='numeric' />" );
```

NOT ADVISED **

You can also override jQuery's append() method to always fire the "appended" event.

```
var oldAppend = $.fn.append;
$.fn.append = function( el )
{
   oldAppend.call( this , el ); // DONT convert el to a JQuery object before passing it to oldAppend
   $(el).trigger("appended");
   return $(el); // to allow chaining to work
}
```

But this will apply to ALL append() calls, wether you want it or not and might possibly break something as I've not investigated stability of this override.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what to do when you are appending this input among much more code?

Comment: Search and replace really, or create a helper method, but you still need to search and replace. There's not really a clean easier way. You could override jQuery's .append() method to always fire an "appended" event, but I would seriously advice against that.

Comment: the .live() method was deprecated in version 1.7 of jQuery, and .bind() is on it's way out as well - in case anyone might be copying this example directly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with BGerrissen by using custom events.

Regarding your question:
If you're adding more html than just the input you could scan the whole html snippet like below:

```
var html = '';
html += '<div>';
html += '<input class="numeric" />';
html += '</div>';

var $html_to_add = $(html);

// add html to dom

if ($html_to_add.find('input.numeric').length > 0) {
  // trigger event   
}
```